# Check graphics card activity

Tags: graphics, cuda

I have an application installed which can make use of my CUDA graphics card, but I'm not sure if I have it configured correctly. Is there a way to check the graphics card activity (throughput, power draw, anything which will tell me if it is being utilised)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the proprietary nvidia drivers (otherwise CUDA doesn't work anyway, I think)? If so, you can run the `nvidia-smi` command in a terminal:

```
nvidia-smi -a
```

This gives you – among other infos – the GPU utilization in %.